# JQuery: how to stop scrolling and reactivate it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop the scroll event after certain scroll position and reactivate it using a callback function.

**Script:**

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if(scroll = 520) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 5500}, 300);
    }, 1500);
}
```

Now I would like to remove the stop() event after 2 seconds or after a certain scroll position.

Comment: u mean do you want to disable scroll for 2 secs?

Comment: Yes, I would like to disable scroll event for 2 seconds.

Comment: kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/se2s75tL/  something similar??

Comment: instead of `setTimeout` use `$('body').stop().delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: 5500});`